# Cometchat, getting volley Library error com.android.volley.ServerError 206 while trying to login

Tags: android, android-volley, cometchat

As I am able to create new user from same url but unable to Login in cometchat

```
   cometchat.login(url, "username","password", new Callbacks() 


        @Override
        public void successCallback(JSONObject success) {
            Log.d("Success-->", success + "");
        }


       @Override
       public void failCallback(JSONObject fail) {
       Log.d("Fail Login-->", fail + "");
       //createUser();
      }
      });
```

Response:
`{
    "code": "206",
    "message": "com.android.volley.ServerError"
}`

Comment: `206 Partial Content` have you checked the APIs documentation?

Comment: I have checked the error codes but their is no such error code available    https://support.cometchat.com/documentation/php/android-chat-sdk/error-codes/

Comment: Have you tried using the API with a generic REST client on your PC?

Comment: I tried calling Api using postman I am getting blank response.I am not sure if I am doing it wrong.

Answer (score -1):

It will issue on server side..
so check & test.

Answer (score -2):

The code reference mentioned in the query for SDK seems of an older version. We can ask to refer to the new SDK version 6.3.2 and create a support ticket if there is an issue on/for this. In the New SDK function name is "loginCallbacks"